# SortableAsyncListView sort

Tags: sorting, filter, null, field, graniteds

```
    <s:DataGrid id="materialsList">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <c:SortableAsyncListView list="{materials}" />
        </s:dataProvider>
        ....
```

materials is PagedQuery.
When I'm sorting by GridColumn with complex dataField ("group.name") I'll getting sort[0]=null and procedure on server-side can't order materials by this field. How to sort SortableAsyncListView by complex field?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why sorting would not work with complex field.
Which version of Flex SDK are you using ?